# How do I add a partial's current folder to the rails view path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, render, view-path

I have a set of partials that are used to update a section of a form depending on the user's choice from a drop-down menu.  There are a lot of different choices, so rather than having a view folder like this:

```
app/views/myview/
  _choice001.html.erb
  _choice002.html.erb
  ...
  _choice998.html.erb
  _choice999.html.erb
  _form.html.erb
  _sharedchoicestuff1.html.erb
  _sharedchoicestuff2.html.erb
  edit.html.erb
  new.html.erb
```

I want to lay it out like this:

```
app/views/myview/
  choices/
    _choice001.html.erb
    _choice002.html.erb
    ...
    _choice998.html.erb
    _choice999.html.erb
    _sharedchoicestuff1.html.erb
    _sharedchoicestuff2.html.erb
  _form.html.erb
  edit.html.erb
  new.html.erb
```

If I do that, then I know I need to change `render :partial => whatever` to `render :partial => "myview/choices/#{whatever}"` which is OK in the form, but I don't want to have to change it in all the choice templates.  Is there a way to add '.' to the view path so I can still have `render :partial => 'sharedchoicestuff1'` in the choice templates.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a helper for that:

```
def render_choice(name)
  render "myview/choices/#{name}"
end
```